# How to interpret whether overfitting or underfitting with my model happened and how to improve my acccuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am developing a license plate recognition algorithm. My dataset contains 150 000 train, 30.000 test and 680 validation images. My model structure is:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
the_input (InputLayer)          (None, 64, 128, 3)   0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 64, 128, 48)  3648        the_input[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pooling1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 32, 64, 48)   0           conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 32, 64, 48)   0           pooling1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv2D)                  (None, 32, 64, 64)   76864       dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pooling2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 16, 64, 64)   0           conv2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 16, 64, 64)   0           pooling2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3 (Conv2D)                  (None, 16, 64, 128)  204928      dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pooling3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 8, 32, 128)   0           conv3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 8, 32, 128)   0           pooling3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 32768)        0           dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 160)          5243040     flatten_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 64)           10304       dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out1 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out2 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out3 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out4 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out5 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out6 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out7 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out8 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out9 (Dense)                    (None, 23)           1495        dense_2[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 5,552,239
Trainable params: 5,552,239
Non-trainable params: 0
________________________________________________________________________________ 
__________________
```

When I try to recognize plate number from validation images it recognizes correctly only 18/680. How can I to understand why the train and test accuracy values are high, but this model cannot recognize validation images and test images, too, after training? How can I improve my model?

And it plotting such plots:

[image: Model accuracy which has multiplied all outputs]

[image: Model loss]

Comment: The plots seem to look ok. With such high capacity models as yours it is usually hard to overfit. The test accuracy is improving so I think you can train for more epochs.

Comment: Please try to be more specific https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: You data set is 150 000 images, but how many images do you use to train the model? If over fitting happens, your train accuracy will increase and your validation accuracy will decrease in each epoch. so compare train and validation accuracy to find out about over fitting.

Comment: @Taher I use 150.000 train images and 30.000 test images. So it recognizes correctly only 18/680 validation images.

Comment: @Vlad Ok I will try, you mean nearby 100-150 epochs?

Comment: @NikitaBelov, For large capacity models (i.e. number of parameters >> number of training samples) you can [train longer and you will generalize better](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08741.pdf). How much longer? Keep training as long as you see improvement and you have enough patience.

Comment: I think 680 images for validation is not enough and it can't prevent overfitting. Mostly we use 10fold validation which in your case it will be 15000 image to validate the model! Increase validation data and then train for more epochs, then compare your train and validation and test accuracy

Comment: @Taher Maybe the problem with loss func? I used categorical crossenrtopy

Comment: @NikitaBelov, + I think you labeled wrongly train/test error/loss in your plots. The labels of curves should be swapped since it is very unusual that you have test accuracy higher than train accuracy.

Comment: @Vlad I checked it recently, everything is fine with labeling

Comment: Shuffle your train data enough, and train for longer epochs. That would be my suggestion. I am not sure if you use a validation set during training(is it what you call 'test'?); but validation loss and accuracy plots should be informative enough to see if the training is going well.